# How to execute flink sql tasks regularly every day？

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

Now, I use java TimerTask to implement it. The problem is that the flink environment is in TimerTask, which causes the submitted job to fail to recognize the job and report an error.

[flink submit error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikmen.png)

You can see that the flink environment is running in TimerTask

code show ：

```
public class DimJob {
private static StreamExecutionEnvironment env;
 private  static EnvironmentSettings build;
 private static StreamTableEnvironment tenv;

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

             env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

            env.setParallelism(1);

             build = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance()
                    .inStreamingMode()
                    .useBlinkPlanner()
                    .build();
             tenv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env, build);



        }
    };

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    long daySpan = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    calendar.set(year, month, day, 3, 00, 00);
    Date time = calendar.getTime();
    long time1 = time.getTime();



    System.out.println(time);

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(timerTask,time,24*60*60*1000);



}
```

}

Comment: Providing code instead of images of code helps to get so much faster recommendations from the community

Comment: You could use something like cron or airtable to handle the timing and orchestration, and use Flink's CLI or REST API to launch the jobs.